# How to filter the rows where the Total is zero in Crystal Reports

Tags: crystal-reports

I want to take out all the rows which has total values as zero.

Ex: I am getting ten rows from database and they have a column 'Total' and 5 rows have 'Total' as Zero,I don't want to display those rows in Crustal report.

Any help is really appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Use **Select Expert**; Total not equal to 0.